# Criar uma instância do jQuery apartir de um array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, array

Tenho o seguinte array:

`var elementos = [$("#elemento1"), $("#elemento2"), $("#elemento3")]`

preciso criar uma função que "converta" esse array em uma instância do jQuery, para mim poder usar as funções do jQuery em todos ao mesmo tempo.

Eu tentei isso:

```js
var elementos = [$("#elemento1"), $("#elemento2"), $("#elemento3")];

$(elementos).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="elemento1">Elemento 1</p>
<p id="elemento2">Elemento 2</p>
<p id="elemento3">Elemento 3</p>
```

Mas não obtive sucesso, sei que o melhor seria usar o each. Mas isso é possível?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer de duas maneiras, ou iteras a array e escondes com o jQuery ([exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/88oydkfk/))

```
elementos.forEach(function($el){ $el.hide();});
```

ou usas virgulas no seletor e recebes uma coleção jQuery com 3 objetos ([exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/88oydkfk/1/))

```
var $els = $('#elemento1, #elemento2, #elemento3');
$els.hide();
```

Dependendo de como estás a receber esses seletores podes usar o que te der mais jeito.

Comment: Como você pode ver, eu tentei usar o $(elementos). Mas quando eu tento oculta-los, não vai.

Comment: @SalomãoNeto tens razão. Estava no móvel e li mal. Corrigi e juntei exemplos.